# Limiting probability of Markov chain

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, markov-chains, markov-process

So the problem is: Let $X$ be a Markov chain with state space $E = ${a,b}  and transition matrix  $$p=\begin{bmatrix}0.4 &0.6 \\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

and suppose that a reward of $g(i,j)$ units is received for every jump from $i$ to $j$ where
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}3 &2 \\-1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n}g(X_m, X_{m+1})$$

The answer is $\frac 9{8}$.

But there are no steps to the answer. I really appreciate if you could show me how to get to the answer, thanks!

Comment: If the distribution is currently stationary, then the expected return is $\pi_a(0.4 \cdot 3 + 0.6 \cdot 2)+\pi_b(-1)=2.4\pi_a-\pi_b$. Why is this the long term return?

Comment: @Ian The question asks for the limiting distribution of the reward rate - not the expected reward rate.

Comment: @Math1000 What I said is that the long term average return is *equal* to the (ensemble) average return under the stationary distribution. This is not trivial but it is true.

Comment: @Math1000 It also does not ask for the distribution, it asks for the long term time average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X_0 = b$. Let $W_0=0$ and $$W_{n+1} = \inf\{m>W_n: X_n=b\}. $$ The $W_n$ are independent with common distribution
$$\mathbb P(W_1=k) = \left(\frac25\right)^{k-2}\frac35,\ k=2,3,\ldots $$ and so $\{W_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ is a renewal process. Let $R_n$ be the reward accumulated between $W_{n-1}$ and $W_n$. Then the $R_n$ are also independent with common distribution $$\mathbb P(R_1 = 1+3k) =   \left(\frac25\right)^k\left(\frac35\right), k=0,1,2,\ldots$$
The mean interrenewal time is $$\mathbb E[W_1] = \sum_{k=2}^\infty k\ \mathbb P(W_1=k) =  \sum_{k=2}^\infty k\left(\frac25\right)^{k-2}\frac35 = \frac83 $$
and the mean reward accumulated
$$\mathbb E[R_1] =\sum_{k=0}^\infty (1+3k)\ \mathbb P(R_1=1+3k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(1+3k)\left(\frac25\right)^{k-2}\frac35 = 3. $$
It follows from the renewal reward theorem that both the long-run time average reward rate and the long-run average expected reward are given by 
$$\frac{\mathbb E[R_1]}{\mathbb E[W_1]}=\frac3{8/3}=\frac98. $$